# Trouble wrting to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I' am new to Python and trying to write into a merged cell within Excel. I can see the data that is already stored within this cell/row, so I know its there. However when I try to overwrite it nothing happens.

I have tried messing with the index and header as well but nothing seems to work.

> import pandas as pd
> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>
> Read the excel file into a pandas DataFrame
> df = pd.read_excel(file here', sheet_name='Sheet1')
> print(df.iloc[8, 2])
>
> Make the changes to the DataFrame
> df.iloc[8, 2] = "Bob Smith"
>
> Load the workbook
> book = load_workbook(file here)
> writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file here, engine='openpyxl')
> writer.book = book
>
> Write the DataFrame to the first sheet
> df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
>
> Save the changes to the Excel file
> writer.save()

Comment: It would be more appreaciated if you show your code as is; text formatted as code. Include comments if you wish as you would normally in code.

Comment: Should be updated now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import *
file="C:/Users/OneDrive/Bureau/draftExcel.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='sheet1')
df.iat[5,0]='cell is updated'
print(df) # to check first in the terminal if the content of the cell is updated
book=load_workbook(file)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='sheet1',index=False)
writer.close()
```

I tried to make an example from what you explained because you didn't show your code, so I hope it was helpful.

Instead of using `.iloc` I used `.iat` so you can update the data in a specific cell in your DataFrame using column_index instead of column_label.

Remember that the Excel file you are working on must be closed while you are editing data with python, if it is open you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this to work after adjusted the location. Sorry for my format being incorrect. I did what it said and used Ctrl q on the code. Anyways thank you.